# \newcommand and its intricacies

Tags: macros, conditionals

I recently came across the following command:

```
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}
```

Well, this is close to the syntax laid out on p.845 of TLC, but I still don't understand it. My interpretation is this:

A newcommand, `minitab`, is being defined.  The command has an optional argument of 2 (the first 
pair of square brackets) and a default argument of `c` (the second pair of square brackets).

Whilst the optional argument is 2, it  could be anything from 0 to 9.

The default argument, `c`, only becomes operative when the optional argument has been (a) specified, or (b) does not exist.

That default argument, `c`, does not of itself mean center. It could, for example, be used as a power:  a$^{c}$.

So then,

1. Have I got this right thus far? If so,
2. How does the tabular command tell (a) from (b)?
3. What's the significance of the non-curly bracketed argument within tabular?

An example would be nice.

Answer (score 10):

**Attention:** there is an error in your code. You missed closing brace `}` before `[2]`.

The code

```
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}
```

defines the command `\minitab` which has two arguments.

The 1st is optional and has default value `c` (which will be used if you don't use another value). It is used to determine the alignment of the single column of `tabular`. So it could be also `r`ight or `l`eft.

The second argument is obligatory and it is in fact the content for the `tabular`.

So you can use the command as

```
\minitab{foo and foo}
```

or

```
\minitab[l]{foo and foo}
```

Recall that options for a command are passed in brackets and mandatory arguments in braces. `\command[<optional>]{<mandatory>}`.

**Edit:**

*command name:* `\minitab`

*number of arguments:* `[2]` (so the `#1` is optional; the `#2` is mandatory)

*default value for `#1`:* `[c]` (will be overridden if you pass another valid value)

*what to do with the arguments?* use `#2` inside the `tabular` as its contents; use `#1` for the column alignment in `tabular`.

**(!)** so you have to use `{#1}` in the definition. Also, for example, if you want to insert a right border you should use `{#1|}`. The braces are important to group.

Recall that the right way to use a `tabular` is:

```
\begin{tabular}{cols}
content...
\end{tabular}
```

**In resume:** `\minitab[l]{a lot of text}` will be the same as

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
a lot of text
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Well, yes, but the thing that threw me(and still does) is that there's an argument in the code that has neither.

Comment: @william, sorry. What do you mean by *has neither*? Which argument are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the {#1}#2 part of the code. Shouldn't it be {#1}{#2}?

Comment: @william, no.  You don't need to use braces to tell what to do with the arguments inside the command. The braces around `#1` is necessary because `tabular` needs it. When you define the alignment for a column you have to use `{c}` or `{l}`. But when you write the contents of the `tabular` you don't need to write it within braces.

Comment: Sigur, I think that's got it. On reflection, what threw me was the fact that there was part of a command without braces and, never having seen such an animal, I though something was wrong. Your explanation makes sense.

Comment: @william, please, see the edited. You missed a brace.